# Prove that a Polynomial ring is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

so I shall prove that a Polynomial ring [K] is a vector space. How do I do that?
I was thinking of just going down all axioms one by one.. but I don't really know how to prove them for a polynomial ring.

Comment: What is a "vector room"?

Comment: I meant vector space.. I'm sorry english is not my first language

Comment: I think going down the axioms one by one is exactly what you're supposed to do... where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to prove the axioms for a polynomial ring..
  How do I prove that x+y = y+x for example (commutative).. (x+y) +z = x+(y+z).. etc

Comment: It is a $k$-algebra   b y  d e f i n i t i o n

Answer (score 2):

To check that $K[X]$ is a vector space, you need to know how addition and multiplication by elements of $K$ are defined in $K[X]$ (the vector space structure ignores the more general multiplication of polynomials with each other). Polynomials are completely determined by knowing for each $i$ their coefficient of $X^i$. Addition is defined so that the coefficient of $X^i$ in $P+Q$ is just the sum of the coefficients of $X^i$ in $P$ and in $Q$, for any $i$. Multiplication by a scalar $\lambda\in K$ also does not mix coefficients from different powers of $X$: the coefficient of $X^i$ in $\lambda P$ is $\lambda$ times the coefficient of $X^i$ in$~P$. This means that to check the axioms of vector spaces, all of which state that certain equalities always hold, you can fix some $i$ (symbolically: you never actually choose a concrete value for it), and check that the coefficients of $X^i$ on both sides of the equality match. This is very easy, for each axiom.

Comment: I am not the OP and this question was answered a long time ago—but I see you are still active on MSE and thought I would try my luck. I am just a little confused as to what the basis of the polynomial ring $K[x]$ is. Could you help me out? Specifically, what is the basis of $\mathbb{R}[t]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[t]$?

Comment: @user8253417 There are of course many possible bases, but there is one that stands out as being natural and simple, often called the canonical basis of the polynomial ring, and that is the set (or list) of _monomials_ $X^k$ where $k$ runs over all natural numbers (which as I hope you agree includes $0$, so the constant polynomial $X^0$ is the initial element of this basis). Almost by definition, every polynomial is a (always finite) linear combination of monomials, and is so in a unique way.

Answer (score 0):

Given any set $A$, the set of all functions $A \to K$, with  pointwise addition and scalar multiplication, is a vector space over $K$.

The set of all functions $A \to K$ that have finite support is a vector subspace.

The ring of polynomials $K[X]$ can be identified with the set of all functions $\mathbb N \to K$ that have finite support and so is a vector space over $K$.